# Is there a way to limit phpdbg to specific files or paths?

Tags: phpdbg

While stepping through code with PHPDBG, is there an easy way to skip over code from other paths.

Specifically, I'm stepping through lots of code for phpunit/mock or composer's class-loader while trying to track down a failure in my code that phpunit found.

"next" appears to be "step into".

Is there a way to "step out of" or better way to skip debugging sections of a code-base?

Comment: Is the `finish` command doing the trick? Also `next` should be "step over" (`step` is "step into").

Comment: I agree "next" is documented as "step over", but at "new ThatClass", "next" dove into composer's auto-loader for me. Same with "$this->getMock(...)"

Comment: What version of phpdbg are you using? There may be older versions which are buggy. If that happens with next, this definitely is a bug.

Comment: "phpdbg 0.5.0 (built: Jan 18 2017 19:13:23)"  available to Amazon Linux on EC2.  (yum install php70-dbg) which doesn't seem right, since phpdbg's website lists 0.4.0